# MySQL Visitor/Hit Counter Sorting Statistics

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I'm building a Visitor & Hit counter for my website, where of course a visitor is a unique ip's per day and hits is just each time the page is requested!

I've already made the datebase and the System to insert and update a table where I keep the statistics!

What I am struggling with is, how to sort the date and then show it. Well I know how I want to show it, but I need it sorted correctly, **and with the least amount of queries**

First this is my table structure, and the current **table name** is **"testing_statistics"**

```
url  - varchar(256)
ip   - int(11)
date - datetime
```

I don't know if that's the 100% best way, but that's how I'm storing it currently, if any of you have a better idea feel free to tell me. **The ip is converted to a long though PHP so it can be stored as an integer**

Then I want all todays hits & visitors, all yesterdays hits & visitors, all current month's hits & visitors and last the total hits & visitors!

#### Here is an image of what I'm trying to get

[image]

I know how to make the layout with CSS, it's just the sorting/getting the data from the database.

---

This is how I currently get the total amount of hits of each url.

```
$query = "SELECT `url`, COUNT(*) as `hits` FROM `testing_statistics` GROUP BY `url`";
```

This is how I currently get the amount of hits today of each url.

```
$query = "SELECT `url`, COUNT(*) as `count2` FROM `testing_statistics` WHERE DATE(`date`) = CURDATE() GROUP BY `url`";
```

I don't really know how to get the rest, and how to get the **total visitors of each url**. So that's what I need some help with and how to puts them together so I don't create a query for each process (Though if not possible, I can live with creating a new query each time)

---

I'm really thankful if anybody can help me, even if it's just with some of the things! and the less queries, the better. (Though it really doesn't matter)

Comment: your queries look OK. What part is not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the total visitors, you can use `count(distinct ip)`.  The queries look like:

```
SELECT `url`, COUNT(*) as `hits`, count(distinct ip) as visitors
FROM `testing_statistics`
GROUP BY `url`
```

And:

```
SELECT `url`, COUNT(*) as `count2`, count(distinct ip) as visitors
FROM `testing_statistics`
WHERE DATE(`date`) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY `url`
```

You can actually do both in one query using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT `url`, COUNT(*) as `hits`, count(distinct ip) as visitors,
       sum(case when DATE(`date`) = CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end) as TodayHits,
       count(distinct case when DATE(`date`) = CURDATE() then ip end) as TodayVisitors
FROM `testing_statistics`
GROUP BY `url`
```

Comment: That's cool, but how can I do the yesterday and current month? if you know that of course.

Comment: @ChristianVallentin . . . The same idea.  Just add variables that define yesterday and last month.  Hint:  use `adddate()` and `interval`.